# Referring to object on other page

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have written a function to remove an iFrame, however the iFrame I want to remove is called in another php-script. I am wondering how i can refer to this script. This is the code for when the iFrame would be in the same script:

```
function removeFrame(framename,action){
    iFrameObject = document.getElementById(framename);
    iFrameObject.style.display = action;
}
```

So i want something like 'otherpage.php.document.getElementbyId(framename)' but I don't really know how to do this..

Comment: What you're asking for isn't clear.  Can you instead describe what would happen from the user's perspective?

Comment: Well, I have a page which contains 2 iframes. In the first iframe I have a form with a submit button. When the user clicks this button, the second iFrame should dissapear. Does that make the question any clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer your question, I would highly recommend avoiding situations like this - communication between frames - if at all possible because it becomes messy very quickly.

However, you can accomplished what you're asking for with a small modification to your code.  The amended function will when invoked from the `iframe` or from the parent window itself.  Keep in mind, though, that inter-window communication are subject to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

```
function removeFrame(framename,action){
    iFrameObject = window.parent.document.getElementById(framename);
    iFrameObject.style.display = action;
}
```

This change involves pointing to the current `window`'s parent, which in the case of the `iframe` is the page that embeds it.  When the current `window` has no real parent window, `window.parent` references the current window (which explains why this function works on the parent page or within an iframe).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed! And indeed, I'll try avoiding this situation the next time, but I didn't really know what I was doing when I started and now I don't feel like starting over :).